# I am using flutter SDK 3.3.8 and getting a issue while comparing null values after converting them to string

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, logical-operators

I am using google sign in and compares the values for getting the user, my code is:

```
await _googleSignIn.signIn().then((value) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Google sign in value:$value');
  }
  print("user email:${value?.email.toString()}");

  ///check profile available or not
 
  if (value?.email.toString().trim() != "" &&
      value?.email.toString() != "null") {
    print("here we are>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    //navigateToHomePage();
  }
});
```

value?.email is null here but the condition gives true and run the code that is inside in if condition.

I would like to know that it valid or not to convert null value into string for comparison?

Comment: You may need check whether value is null or not

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way would be to check if `value?.email` itself is Null or not

For example:

```dart
if (value?.email != "" &&
      value?.email != null) {
    print("here we are>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    //navigateToHomePage();
  }
```